# PyCharm/CProfiler Call Graph not loading any text

Tags: pycharm, profiler

I am using the inbuilt cprofiler of PyCharm to analyze the runtime of my code. The "statistic" tab works fine, but I can't see any text labels on the call graph. Maybe I am misunderstanding the purpose of this tab, since I'm new to profilers and runtime analysis. I was expecting it to show some method names and such.

[image: The call graph]

EDIT:
It worked when changing it to "organic layout" or "directed orthogonal layout", which look horrible though. Still doesn't work with any other layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to delete this question, since the problem was literally as simple as not being zoomed in enough. But there are likely to be more people than me with that problem, i though I might just close it.

If this is against the rules of SO in some way please let me know :)